# Grouping data by bin with np.digitize

Tags: python, binning

I am looking for a way to average the data that I have in an array based on how far it is from a certain pixel. To achieve this I have made an array `r` which contains the distances to the center. There is a second array `data` that contains the counts that can be found in the pixel at that distance.

Now I have split the entire dataset (that goes from 0-1150) into 60 bins and then digitized the data to get an array that tells me which value belongs into which bin.

```
bins = np.linspace(0,60*20, 60)
digitized = np.digitize(rr, bins)
```

Is there a smart way to apply digitized to the data so that all points with the same bin value get averaged?

Array `r` has a shape of 380, `data` is the same. So the end result should be an array of 60 elements that has the average of all the binned values in `data` based on which bin was assigned to `digitized`.

Comment: It would help if you mention the shapes of all arrays involved, including the final result.

Comment: Done. Does that help? They are normal 1d arrays.

Comment: What does each element of `data` represent? You mentioned that it "contains the counts that can be found in the pixel at that distance". Could you please explain that?

Comment: Also, what is the desired output? Is it an array of the same size as rr where elements belonging to the same bin will get the same average value?

Comment: Currently It contains the std of the counts, but I need it to be a list of values.

Comment: "Currently It contains the std of the counts". Was that in response to my question about `data`? I'm afraid it didn't help me. What does "the counts" mean here? If `data[3]` contains 20, what does it mean? And preferably, please mention in an edit of your question.

Comment: it just contains singular values. So data[3] is a float. (58 in this case)

Comment: OK, so these are floats that represent the "counts that can be found in the pixel at that distance" . Still, the role of these values in the desired output is not clear, or maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt, although I assume you are looking for something considerably more elegant? :)

```
rr = np.random.randint(0, 15, 1000)
rr_sorted = np.sort(rr)

# Bins
bins = [0, 5, 10, 15]

def assume_sorted_digitized(rr_sorted, bins):
    dig = np.digitize(rr_sorted, bins)
    bin_nr, index = np.unique(dig, return_index=True)
    index_adjusted = np.append(index[1:], len(rr_sorted))
    bin_average = np.zeros_like(bins).astype(np.float32)
    last_idx = 0
    for idx, bin_i in zip(index_adjusted, bin_nr):
        bin_average[bin_i] = rr_sorted[last_idx:idx].mean()
        last_idx = idx
    return bin_average

def nonsorted_digitized(rr, bins):
    dig = np.digitize(rr, bins)
    bin_average = np.zeros_like(bins).astype(np.float32)
    for idx in np.unique(dig):
        bin_average[idx] = rr[dig == idx].mean()
    return bin_average

%timeit assume_sorted_digitized(rr_sorted, bins)
%timeit nonsorted_digitized(rr, bins)
```

Assuming it's sorted gives a slight performance boost

```
86.5 µs ± 5.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
113 µs ± 6.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```